# Node.js: Create a watchdog for an object with Proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, proxy

edit: It is an object Proxy, see also the answer however don't understand why console.log( watchDog ) produce so many http and path related stuff, don't understand the association.

---

I want to keep an eye on the changes of an object however the Proxy object seems to be a Proxy server object.

What I did to test the feature:

```
var myObject = {},
    watchDog = new Proxy( myObject, {
                            set: function (target, key, value) 
                            {
                                console.log(key, 'changed to ', value );
                                target[key] = value;
                            }
                          }); 
 myObject.test = 1;
```

It will never be triggered because it doesn't seem to be an object Proxy. When I dump the contents (`console.log( watchDog );`) of the proxy object, it shows a huge amount of stuff, something like this:

```
   .............
   .............
   .............  
   { http_parser: '2.8.0',
           node: '8.11.3',
           v8: '6.2.414.54',
           uv: '1.19.1',
           zlib: '1.2.11',
           ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
           modules: '57',
           nghttp2: '1.32.0',
           napi: '3',
           openssl: '1.0.2o',
           icu: '60.1',
           unicode: '10.0',
           cldr: '32.0',
           tz: '2017c' },
        arch: 'ia32',
        platform: 'win32',
        release:
         { name: 'node',
           lts: 'Carbon',
           sourceUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3.tar
    gz',
           headersUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-he
    ders.tar.gz',
           libUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.3/win-x86/node.lib' }

        argv:
         [ 'F:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
           'L:\\Utils\\codebeat\\SerialInputDevice\\server\\app.js' ],
        execArgv: [],
        env:
         { ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
           APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming',
           CLASSPATH: '.;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7_32\\lib\\ext\\QTJava.z
    p',
           CommonProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
           'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
           CommonProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',

 ..............
 ..............

 etc.
```

---

So this is not an object proxy. What can I do to create an object proxy and not a proxy server object?

See also

- [MDN Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
- [ChromeDev Proxy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/es2015-proxies)

Comment: Can you elaborate what's your case? Why exactly do you need to watch on object changes and why are you changing `myObject` and not `watchDog`? This is not clear from the code.

Comment: @estus : see also the answer and comments below.

Comment: I saw it. It wasn't clear why you insisted on watching myObject instead of using watchDog. *It is not possible to watch the changes instead of wrapping it?* It's possible to tamper prototype chain with Proxy and watch myObject itself, but this may have undesirable consequences. It depends on what is this object and how it's used.

Comment: @estus, thanks for your reply. Well I can remember watch and observe which are removed from js. I used the myObject and not the Proxy because of knowledge of the past, I thought it was the same however it isn't. Now I understand why it is called proxy, proxy is the access manager of the object and the object is the container that holds the information. What I try to do is make an object that cannot be changed after it is initialized once. This is working now.

Comment: I miss Object.observe, but that's it. Yes, if a proxy works as is, look no further. The only real alternative to Object.observe is polling, which is inefficient and also asynchronous. As I mentioned, for plain object prototype chain can be tampered, like `obj.__proto__ = new Proxy({}, ...)`. May not work as intended if an object isn't plain or has existing promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the existing code example:

```
watchDog.test = 5
```

Does produce output. The original `myObject` isn't modified, rather a 'shell' is created around it that can be used to intercept interaction before allowing interaction with the original object.

In Chrome (I just tried), this outputs `test changed to 5`. However the documentation for [`set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) says about the return value:

> The set method should return a boolean value. Return true to indicate that assignment succeeded. If the set method returns false, and the assignment happened in strict-mode code, a TypeError will be thrown.

The example code shows the return of different values. That code uses [`Reflect.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set), to handle the truthiness of the return. Try this:

```
var myObject = {},
    watchDog = new Proxy( myObject, {
                            set: function (target, key, value) 
                            {
                                console.log(key, 'changed to ', value );
                                target[key] = value;
                                return Reflect.set(...arguments);
                            }
                        }); 
watchDog.test = 1;
```

Comment: Appreciate the fast answer however the proxy is to watch the other object to change. Tried it anyway and this is what happen: TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'test' Besides, anyway, it is a server Proxy and not a object Proxy, what can I do to create and object Proxy instead of a server Proxy object.

Comment: The `return Reflect...` comes from the MDN example, and is built to address a `TypeError`.

Comment: I think I will get it in a moment, thanks for patience ;-) Return true did the trick. So I need to use the proxy instead to detect changes, instead of the object itself? Now I understand the name 'Proxy' (earlier it was watch or observe), however it is not a watch, watch dog. I need to use this as main object and return this watchdog object, right? So the myObject is just a container and the watchDog is the manager of the object. That;s different. It is not possible to watch the changes instead of wrapping it?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. Javascript isn't my strong suit, but as far as I know, a Proxy is the closest you'll get to what you want.

Comment: Hi Alex, it is working now, thanks for the help! Do you know why console.log( watchDog ) output so many http and path stuff (see my question)?